# Cronômetro de Tempo Inativo

Tags: delphi

Tenho um componente Label que mostra o número de arquivos em uma pasta.

Durante o download de vários arquivos o número exibido pelo TLabel muda (conforme os arquivos na pasta).

Como faço para quando o caption do Label parar de ser alterado (ou parar de exibir valores diferentes) ser disparado um cronômetro a partir do zero?

Para um cronômetro simples uso o seguinte código:

```
procedure TFrmMain.TimerAtivTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Cronometro para Tempo em Atividade
LblTempoAtividade.Caption := 'Em Atividade:   ' + FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', TempoAntigo - NOW);
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Seria necessário um novo Timer para isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em TfrmMain, declare uma variável (inicialize-a com 0):

`private
    TempoAntigo: TTime;
    ...`

Quando receber um novo arquivo, atualize a variável:

`procedure TFrmMain.TimerAtivTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if novo_arquivo_na_pasta then
  begin
    LblTempoAtividade.Caption := 
      'Em Atividade:   ' + FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', now - TempoAntigo);
    TempoAntigo := now;
  end;
  ...
end;`